# Why does Attr inherit from Node in the DOM?

Tags: html, xml, dom, interface, attr

according to [the DOM Core](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-BBACDC08),

> Attr objects inherit the Node interface, but since they are not actually child nodes of the element they describe, the DOM does not consider them part of the document tree.

and also

> The DOM takes the view that attributes are properties of elements rather than having a separate identity from the elements they are associated with

Given this, what is the advantage of `Attr` objects inheriting from `Node`?

The [DOM Spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) states:

> Attr nodes participate in a tree for historical reasons; they never have a (non-null) parent or any children and are therefore alone in a tree.

which is a partial answer, but I'm wondering if anyone has any deeper explination of `Attr`'s `Node` inheritance and tree participation than simply "historical reasons".

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, most questions I've found revolve around the behavior of `Attr` objects, rather than the rationale behind their structure.

Comment: The W3C DOM spec is abstract and language-independent, and concrete realisations of the DOM interface in different programming languages (Java, JavaScript, C#) have handled this question differently. Which programming language are you concerned with?

Comment: I primarily interact with HTML DOM implementations using JavaScript, however the aim of this question was to understand the decisions behind the spec itself, independent of implementation. Was the choice of having Attr inherit Node made with a particular language in mind? If so, that is interesting and I would love to know more.

Comment: I wasn't involved in the development of the W3C spec, but I think there was a real tension between people who thought the spec was just syntactic sugar for a Java binding, and those who considered it genuinely language-independent. It was a large committee and I think there were many divergences of viewpoint, which is why it's such a mess.

Comment: The editor of the Living DOM specification tried very hard not to make Attr inherit from Node. For a substantial period of time it didn't. I don't know what made him change his mind, but in strongly typed, object-oriented languages like Java, long existing and widely used libraries (e.g. Xerces) had Attr inherit from Node as the original DOM required. That meant that any code which cast Attr to Node would break if it tried to use a DOM implementation library that didn't have that inheritance. So all the existing libraries implementations could not be extended to support the new DOM.

Comment: The above could explain why Attr _still_ inherits from Node, and what that "historical reasons" comment is implying, but not of course, why Attr _originally_ inherited from Node.

Comment: @Alohci it's not so much libraries like Xerces, as the org.w3.dom.Node interface which is part of the JDK, and which any DOM library has to conform to. The JDK works with very strict backwards compatibility rules: even when they know a design is bad, they never change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a "why" question, you need to be very clear whether you are asking

- what are the potential benefits of this decision?, or
- historically, what arguments were put forward and why did individual committee members vote the way they did (if indeed there was a discussion and a vote)?

In most cases the second question is unanswerable, though in a few cases (such as the Annotated XML specification by Tim Bray) you can at least see the rationale put forward by one of the editors.

To me the decision feels like a compromise. Attributes have many properties in common with other nodes, so there's an advantage in having them implement the same interface; but there's baggage that you don't really want because it might add unnecessary cost, like having a link to the containing element.

Frankly, DOM is not a good piece of design, and it's very hard to say why it made so many design mistakes, other than that it was put together by a committee in a hurry. Later models such as JDOM and XOM are much better, but sadly not available for Javascript.

Comment: Ultimately I'm looking to understand the benefits and tradeoffs of the decision. I have a hard time understanding how something works without knowing why it works/why it is the way it is. But when it comes to design decisions it seems almost inevitable that your second bullet point will come into play too. Fortunately, both people who have commented and answered so far seem to have some insight into the minds of those making decisions about the DOM, which is welcome context to further a holistic understanding of the spec.